# Kansai variant(s) of ～しちゃ危ない／だめ

Tags: grammar, dialects, conditionals, kansai-ben, modality

What would be some Kansai-ben equivalents to the following two sentences?

> (a) 火遊びしちゃ危ないよ！

> (b) 火遊びしちゃだめだよ！

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a native Kansai-an I have to point out: the natural way to say it is:

> (a) 火遊びしたら危ないで！

> (b) 火遊びしたらアカンで！

It'd be odd to say "しちゃあかんで" as you don't say しちゃ in Kansai dialect.

”してもうたら” has a slightly different meaning and shouldn't be used in this case. "してもうたら" is used to describe the consequence of an action, e.g. 火遊びしてもうたらもう許してもらえへんで or 火遊びしてもうたらもう不良やな

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Makes sense. My answer was partially based on what I've heard people around me use, but it seems that many of them (mostly young people) use a haphazard mix of Kansai-isms and Kanto-isms...

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for! A quick follow-up (that probably doesn't warrant its own post): Do you make/notice any difference in intonation  between the two sentences you wrote?

Comment: @schoekling How would it even be possible to intone 危ない and アカン in the same way?

Comment: @Kimball  I am not talking about the accents of 危ない and アカン, but the intonation of the whole sentences.

Comment: Both sentences can be said with similar intonations. But, with アカン you have slightly more "options" I think.

Comment: @Will: I can imagine! My friends also sometimes put アカン etc. at the end of the sentence without changing the other parts..

Comment: Those 'options' are what I was hoping for! :) Would you mind elaborating on that? In particular, is one of the options to not reset pitch? As if you could treat (b) as mono-clausal, while (a) always has to be bi-clausal?